# Sound Recorder with "Record as" list empty in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound-recorder

I tried today for the first time Sound Recorder,
but the list "Record as" is empty.

Does someone knows why?
Is maybe some other problem I have with Ubuntu since I upgraded to 13.04?
Is it going to be solved with 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I noticed it after upgrading to 13.10.  I can't remember if I used sound recorder after a clean 13.04 install or not.  It worked prior to the clean install I'm sure.  There is a bug reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/1230231